# Gradle custom plugin for wrapping a Maven artifact repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

### Introduction

I am writing a custom plugin for Gradle to allow users to publish artifacts generated by their builds to a corporate Maven repository. I want users to be able to use the standard `maven-publish` plugin to upload their artifacts, but without them knowing the repository's details, i.e. authentication.

Users may run local builds but they cannot publish anything to the repository. The same user-provided build scripts, when running on a build server, will be able to publish. Users may download the plugin and use it locally, but it won't work. It will either fail or do a mock no-op upload to local/dummy repo/whatever, this is not important right now. When running on the build server, the plugin will just "know it" and work properly.

As I said, I want users to use the standard `maven-publish` plugin. I would like something like this for the users' build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    Organization.mavenCorporate() /* this would be it */
}
```

(The `Organization` part is not required, it's just how I have seen it works with Gradle's project extensions, which seem to be currently favored over conventions).

---

### Current status

So far I have been able to get the above piece of the script working to some extent. When I run a build which uses my plugin, it does:

- not fail at syntax check/compile time, so I know Gradle understands this piece of code.
- print some info when the plugin is applied, so I know Gradle is really using it.
- print my (currently hard-coded) repository's name when I do `println Organization.mavenCorporate().name` inside the build script, so I know the extension is working.
- print my repository's name when I do `println project.repositories[0].name` inside the build script, so I know the project knows the repository. The name is the same as the previous print and contains a `System.nanoTime()` to be sure it is not being generated twice. Also, if I print the default object's `toString()` instead of its name, both identifiers are equal.

However, when the build tries to resolve actual dependencies, it fails with the following message:

```
Execution failed for task ':myproject:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myproject:compileClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :myproject
    > Cannot resolve external dependency org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.3 because no repositories are defined.
      Required by:
          project :myproject
[...]
```

What bothers me is the '**because no repositories are defined**' part. I would expect it to fail for a lot of different reasons, but not this one. When I add another repository which does not contain the needed dependencies, it fails with another kind of error.

---

### The code

My plugin is written in Java. I have seen a plugin from the Gradle Plugin Portal which has a very similar purpose, but it's written in Groovy. It simply adds some methods to `project.repositories.metaClass`. I don't know Groovy, but that looks like a quick-and-dirty solution to avoid dealing with Gradle's API in a proper way.

As of now, I have the following:

- The main plugin class:

  ```
  public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
      @Override
      public void apply(Project project) {
          _printVersionInfo(project);
          // this allows the use of Organization methods as Gradle DSL
          project.getExtensions().create("Organization", Organization.class, project);
          // this should add the repo to project's RepositoryManager
          project.getRepositories().add(CustomRepository.getInstance(project));
      }
      [unrelated methods omitted]
  }
  ```
- The custom repository class:

  ```
  public class CustomRepository implements MavenArtifactRepository {
      private static MavenArtifactRepository repo;    
      public static MavenArtifactRepository getInstance(Project project) {
          if (repo == null) {
              DefaultRepositoryHandler drh = (DefaultRepositoryHandler) project.getRepositories(); 
              repo = drh.maven(new CustomRepoAction());   
          }
          return repo;
      }
      [implemented methods from MavenArtifactRepository omitted for brevity; for debugging purposes, every method except getName() and getUrl() currently throws an UnsupportedOperationException]
  }
  ```
- The extension `Organization` class. Contains only the `mavenCorporate()` DSL method, which returns a `MavenArtifactRepository` obtained with the same call to `CustomRepository.getInstance(project)` as in the main plugin class.
- The `CustomRepoAction`class which implements `Action<MavenArtifactRepository>`. Contains only the implementation of `execute` method, which sets the name and URL of the `MavenArtifactRepository` passed as the parameter.

I am using Java 8 and Gradle 3.4. I am relatively new to Gradle as the user, and not really familiar with the new features from Java 7 and 8.

---

### The question

<strike>Am I missing something? Why doesn't Gradle recognize the `MavenRepositoryArtifact` returned by `Organization.mavenCorporate()` as a repository? Do I need to bind the repository with the project, the repository handler, or any kind of manager object that I am not aware of?</strike>

EDIT: Thanks to @lukegv's comment, now I realize I cannot force my custom DSL into `DefaultRepositoryHandler`. I tried something like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven Organization.mavenCorporateAction() /* instance of CustomRepoAction */
}
```

and it works, adds a `MavenArtifactRepository` to project's repositories. But that doesn't keep users from accessing to the repository's internals, i.e. password. However, `RepositoryHandler.maven(Action<? super MavenArtifactRepository> action)` doesn't allow me to add a subclass of `MavenArtifactRepository` in which I could control this behaviour.

Do I need to implement a `RepositoryHandler` and make it the default repository handler for projects? Is that even possible without implementing my own custom `Project` class and messing with Gradle's internals? Is there a clean way of achieving this:

> I want users to be able to use the standard `maven-publish` plugin to
>   upload their artifacts, but without them knowing the repository's
>   details, i.e. authentication.

with decoration, or anything implying minimal or no changes to the default behavior of everything else?

Comment: Could you add the code of your `CustomRepoAction`? Also, I do not really understand why you could need a custom repository class. Just one hint, before I venture to answer your question: `Organization.mavenCorporate()` will **never** add a repository to the repository handler. `repositories { }` is **not** a list, it is a closure. Every possible method (`maven`, `flatDir`, ...) adds a repository **and** returns it. Just returning a repository via a new method won't add it to the repository handler.

Comment: @lukegv You're right, I got it all wrong. I wasn't understanding the mapping between Gradle DSL syntax and the API. I didn't realize that `repositories` is actually `Project.getRepositories()` which returns a `RepositoryHandler` with its own methods already defined.

Comment: @lukegv As of why I need a custom repository class, I don't really know whether I need a custom repository class, a custom repository handler class, both, or something else. All I want is a way for using a secured Maven repository without the users knowing (having to configure in their build.gradle) about repo's security (or even URL).

Comment: @willyjoker did you have any progress with this? Can you share code if yes?

Comment: @KostasDrak nope, this project has been on hold for quite a while. I'll post an answer if I'm ever able to get back at this and find a solution.